При скролле времени на телефонах выбирается значение, как убрать? datetimepicker jquery
Использую datetime-picker@2.5.11 на jquery, на компах все работает без проблем, на телефонах при скролле времени - выбирается значение автоматом. Т.е пользователи не могу прокрутить вниз, когда начинают крутить то выбирается значение по которому "нажали"
Как это пофиксить?


scrollInput:false,
timepickerScrollbar:false



вот это не помогло
В общем, нужно сначала прокрутить вниз, только потом выбрать.
